# ApacheBench and http request in PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a some script, which gets the value from request:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

And I test this script using `ApacheBech(ab)` util. How can I send a value of `php://input` in ApacheBench util? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ab -p POST-file` (File containing data to POST)